# The static field view.GONE should be accessed in a static way?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am building an android app and I have a warning that is not causing any problems however, when I see a warning I like to at least know what is causing it.  The app uses webview.

Here is the bit if code that is causing the warning.

```
ImageView viewSplash;
WebView mWebView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    viewSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewtest(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView View, String url)
        {
            viewSplash.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
    });
}
```

This is the error:

The static field View.GONE should be accessed in a static way.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html for an explanation of what the error message means. Note that it says: "You can also refer to static methods with an object reference like

        instanceName.methodName(args) 

but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class methods." In that case they're talking about static methods instead of static fields, but it's the same idea, and it's discouraged for the same reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I can see one problem which might be relevant. You have a capitalised View as an argument name (see `public void onPageFinished(WebView -> View <-, String url)`). Uncapitalise this.

Edit: the problem was the argument name being the wrong caps, and masking the class access with an instance variable access, which is why you got the error. The better fix would be to sort out the capitalisation.

Comment: When I made this change it gave me an error that "view cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Because you hadn't imported View properly. You shouldn't have to access it with the full class path in that way (with qualified package name). Using Eclipse, implement my change, and then press CTRL-SPACE on the View bit of View.GONE. Browse down to the entry and this will import it. Or press CTRL-O when you have import errors, and select the correct package for importing (android.view.View). Or just shove import android.view.View; at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok just after posting this I fixed the warning...

I changed this:

```
viewSplash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to this:

```
viewSplash.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
```

Comment: If that fixed the problem, then maybe `View` is defined as something other than the `android.view.View` class. Look through your code to see if you accidentally named a variable `View`. In Java, you should always have class names start with a capital letter, and variable names start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Just noticed it's right there in the arguments: `WebView View`. Change it to `WebView view` and then you won't need to refer to the `View` class by its fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

The constant View.GONE or (in my case) Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE are constants within the class Context, they are not to be accessed through a local Context or View. So the error is to reference somethingorother.GONE instead of the View.gone.