# webview Visibility == Invisible

Tags: android

i want to invisile webview , purpose of remove load url . i have try 
`webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` but it is not working there. in my webview i have load one swf file. and also put button there . when i press button `invisible` code fire.
but problem is not invisible or remove webview & loaded data.

So can you help me ?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: ya i have also try but cant able to do that

Comment: Try out this question of Stackoverflow, if it helps.
[WebView query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560145/the-static-field-view-gone-should-be-accessed-in-a-static-way)

Answer (score 2):

i got it by this way `wevview.removeAllViews();`